# I want to authentication user using a express-session but it's given me error

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, express-session

I have a problem in my code, It's:

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'user_id')

But logically it's correct, but I can't solve it so I need help.

This Lines contain Middleware inside it (Authenticate function, Sessions) And AuthController

```
const authenticateUser  = require('../middleware/loginMiddleware');
const UserModel = require('../models/User');
const validator = require('validator');


const checkValid = async (req, res) => {
    const { email, password } = req.body;

    if (validator.isEmail(email) === false) {
        return res.status(400).render('../views/auth/login.ejs', { 'error': 'Error: Invalid email' });
    }

    try {
        const user = await UserModel.findOne({ email, password });

        if (user) {
            authenticateUser(req, res, user);
        } else {
            res.status(400).render('../views/auth/login.ejs', { 'error': 'Invalid login credentials' });
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        res.status(500).render('../views/auth/login.ejs', { 'error': 'An error occurred while checking login credentials' });
    }
};

module.exports = {
    checkValid
};

const express = require('express');
const session = require('express-session');
const sessionCookieLifeTime = 1000 * 60 * 15;
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')
const router = express.Router();

// Set up session middleware
router.use(session({
    secret: "+G2xQz%]/Lk)A8oN*W%xReKj=EcenJ",
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: { maxAge: sessionCookieLifeTime },
    resave: false
}));
router.use(cookieParser());

// Middleware to check if the user is logged in
const checkLogin = (req, res, next) => {
    if (req.session && req.session.user_id) {
        // User is logged in, proceed to the next middleware or route
        next();
    } else {
        // User is not logged in, redirect to the login page or handle it accordingly
        res.redirect('/admin');
    }
};


const authenticateUser = (req, res, User) => {
    if (req.session && req.session.user_id) {
        return res.redirect('/dashboard');
    }

    if (User.email === req.body.email && User.password === req.body.password) {
        req.session.user_id = User._id; 
        console.log('\x1b[32mMessage:\x1b[0m Successfully authenticate user');
        console.log('\x1b[34mSession User id:\x1b[0m ' + req.session.user_id);
        return res.status(200).redirect('/dashboard');
    } else {
        console.log('\x1B[31mError:\x1b[0m', 'Invalid credentials.')
        return res.status(400).render('../views/auth/login.ejs', { 'error': 'Invalid credentials.' });
    }
};

module.exports = {
    authenticateUser,
    checkLogin,
};
```

I tried to solve it more than one time but it's always given me un defined error.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Relevant code and error messages need to be included in your question *as text*, [not as pictures of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/328193).  Just linking to screen shots makes it more difficult for people to help you.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: Seems like there is no `user` in `req.session`

Comment: At which exact line of code is the error thrown?